# How to access size column in groupby

Tags: pandas

Consider the following code.

```
d=pd.DataFrame([[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c'],[2,'a'],[3,'c'],[4,'a'],[4,'c']],columns=['A','B'])
k=d.groupby(d.A).size().to_frame('size')
```

It returns

```
   size
A
1     2
2     2
3     1
4     2
```

Also,

```
k.shape

(4,1)
```

I want to be able to access the size column and the index column but the data frame is only 1 column wide. How do I access both columns?

Comment: `I can't access the size column ` - can you explain more?

Comment: `k['size']`?????

Comment: I want to be able to do k.iloc[0,1] to get the size of 1 as 2. I am unable to do that since there is only one column in k.

Comment: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds is the error.                 
 >>> k['size']
A
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    2
Name: size, dtype: int64

Comment: `k` does have `1` columns, the other `A` is index. just do `k.iloc[0,0]` if you want to get the series `size` values.

Comment: k.iloc[0,0] works. Thank you.

Comment: How do I access the index itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, 'size' column is the only column you can access, the one on the left is simply an index.

If you want to have that index as a column as well you could do the following:

```
d=pd.DataFrame([[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c'],[2,'a'],[3,'c'],[4,'a'],[4,'c']],columns=['A','B'])
k=d.groupby(d.A).size().to_frame('size')

k.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

Now you would be able to access both columns and have a new index.

```
    A   size
0   1   2
1   2   2
2   3   1
3   4   2

k.shape

(4,2)
```

i.e.

```
k['A'][0]
1
```

or

```
k['size'][0]
2
```

Hope this helped!